# What is the correct way to map master-detail class that inserts data into the trigger?

Tags: java, postgresql, jpa, eclipselink

There are triggers in both tables to store the audit log, these triggers insert data in theses audit tables using INSERT INTO and using sequences.

But when inserting data in `table_detail` and `table_master` in the application the eclipselink gets the primary key to link one object to another using: `lastval()` and generates an error because `lastval()` returns the primary key of the audit table and not `table_master` or `table_detail`.

The error are display as: `ERROR: inserting or updating in table "table_detail" violates the foreign key constraint "table_master".`

What should I do to resolve this limitation?
Is there any annotation I can use to make eclipselink use `currval ('names_id_seq')` or `INSERT INTO... RETURNING codigo` instead of `lastval()`?

I have classes like this:

```
@Entity
@Table(name="table_detail")
public class TableDetail {

   @Id
   @Column(name="codigo")
   @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.IDENTITY)
   private Integer codigo;

   [...more fields here...]

   @ManyToOne
   @JoinColumn(name="table_master", referencedColumnName = "codigo")
   private TableMaster masterData;

   [...getters, setters, hash, toString, etc...]
}
```

...

```
@Entity
@Table(name="table_master")
public class TableMaster {

   @Id
   @Column(name="codigo")
   @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.IDENTITY)
   private Integer codigo;


   [...more fields here...]

   @OneToMany(cascade=CascadeType.ALL, mappedBy="masterData")
   private List<TableDetail> listDetail;

   [...getters, setters, hash, toString, etc...]
}
```

Comment: Any reason you are using identity and not sequencing? Sequencing allows preallocation. Even table sequencing might be better for you in this case. Otherwise, you'd have to subclass the PostgreSQLPlatform class and override the buildSelectQueryForIdentity method to execute what you want instead of lastval

Comment: Thanks for answer @Cris, the Sequencing is a difficult path because I would have to refactor the entire project, but I believe it is the only solution. While your suggestion to override the buildSelectQueryForIdentity method is not viable because the method itself does not know which table is being used.

Comment: Not to try and steer you away from the better solution, but if you had buildSelectQueryForIdentity() return null, the buildSelectQueryForIdentity(String seqName, Integer size) method would then be called each time. The seqName can be used by your code to call "currval ('names_id_seq')", or figure out the table name for other calls.